# what is the right way to know all script PIDS that runs under folder

Tags: kill, ps, process-management, lsof

Under the folder `/home/testing/scripts` on a Linux machine, we have 234 different scripts that do sanity and testing

as

```
/home/testing/scripts/test.network.py
/home/testing/scripts/test.hw.py
/home/testing/scripts/test.load.sh
.
.
.
```

in some cases we want to kill all running scripts

so in order to find the running scripts pids we do that

```
lsof /home/testing/scripts/
```

and to kill all pids we use:

```
for proccess in `lsof /home/testing/scripts/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v proccess`; do kill $proccess; done
```

lets say we run only the script - `/home/testing/scripts/test.network.py`

and from  `ps -ef |grep "testing/scripts"` we get

```
root      5793 17546 84 09:20 ?        00:00:00 python3 -u /home/testing/scripts/test.network.py
```

so from `lsof` we should get the same pid number as

```
lsof /home/testing/scripts/
```

now , I just to know if my approach

```
for proccess in `lsof /home/testing/scripts/ | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v proccess`; do kill $proccess; done
```

is good enough to kill all running scripts under `/home/testing/scripts/`

or maybe other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tidy up the command a little, but it seems to me that it's reasonably accurate already. I'd match the filename more tightly to reduce potential mismatches, and I'd ensure that each candidate PID was actually numeric,

```
lsof | awk -v p='^/home/testing/scripts/' '$9~p && $2+0 {print $2}' | sort -u | xargs echo kill
```

Notice the `^` at the beginning of the directory assignment to the `awk` variable `p`. You should also escape characters that could be interpreted as part of a Regular Expression (i.e. `.` should be represented as `\.`, the `*` as `\*`, etc.)

Remove `echo` when you're ready to have the script really perform the kill operation.